Recognize the exact process that sent the keystroke in Python
I'm trying to build a program that recognizes keystrokes and also the exact process that sent it, so the source.
For example, if I press the character 'g' on my keyboard, it should recognize the keyboard as the source, since no app sent the keystroke but the keyboard, then if I run an AutoHotkey script which virtually press the character 'w', the program should say "script.ahk", which is the name of the script; if any process sends a keystroke, the program should say that exact process.
I've tried coding it but ended up on displaying the currently focused window name, not the exact process.
For example if I'm browsing files in explorer.exe and I double click on the AutoHotkey script, the program says explorer.exe instead of the name of the script.
Is it possible to do this recognizing process? Or is impossible to detect the exact process that sent the keystroke?
The code:
import ctypes
import psutil
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyboardListener

# Function to get the active window's title and hwnd (handle) (Windows-specific)
def get_active_window_title():
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    GetForegroundWindow = user32.GetForegroundWindow
    GetWindowText = user32.GetWindowTextW
    GetWindowTextLength = user32.GetWindowTextLengthW

    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow()
    length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
    buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, length + 1)
    return buf.value, hwnd

# Function to get the process name from the window's hwnd (handle)
def get_process_name_from_hwnd(hwnd):
    try:
        # Get the process ID using the window's handle
        pid = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ctypes.byref(pid))
        
        p = psutil.Process(pid.value)
        return p.name()
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        return None

# Function to identify whether the key press is from a physical keyboard or an app
def identify_keypress_source():
    # Get the current active window and its process name
    active_window, hwnd = get_active_window_title()
    process_name = get_process_name_from_hwnd(hwnd)

    # If there's an active window and it's associated with a process, it must be app-generated
    if active_window and process_name:
        return f"app-generated (Process: {process_name})"
    else:
        # If no active window, consider it a physical keyboard input
        return "keyboard"

# Callback for key press events
def on_press(key):
    try:
        keystroke_source = identify_keypress_source()

        if hasattr(key, 'char') and key.char:
            print(f"Key '{key.char}' pressed from {keystroke_source}")
        else:
            print(f"Special key {key} pressed from {keystroke_source}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

# Function to start the listener for keyboard events
def start_key_listener():
    with KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting key press listener...")

    # Start listening to the keyboard
    start_key_listener()


the program should say "script.ahk" The actual process would not be named script.ahk, surely?  The process would be whatever executable program is running/interpreting the script file.

Are you saying that in this case, you specifically do not want the process name, but you want the script name instead?

Both hardware and software input ends up in a single queue. This input is sent to the foreground window (after hook processing).
If all you care about is detecting software input, use def win32_event_filter(msg, data): with the pynput keyboard listener. data is a KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT where LLKHF_INJECTED is set in flags for software generated events. Note that the target window of this input event has not yet been determined during this hook callback.
If you need to know the exact source of the input then things are more complicated.

The RAW input API should be able to tell you which keyboard (USB device) input is coming from. This blog post says the device handle is 0 for software input.
Hooking the SendInput and keybd_event functions in all processes would tell you which process is generating input but I would not recommend doing this and certainly not in Python.

